# Mounting Docker volumes - is the writeable layer used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, volume

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to process a lot of data on AWS. Right now, the input for the scripts I want to run using my parent image is about 20G.

First, I tried just copying the data into my image on the writeable layer (using COPY), but then I got the error

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 20.53 GB
```

`Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /Input/dbsnp_138.b37.vcf: no space left on device`

So I thought that 20G would be too much to just store on my writeable layer.

Then I looked at mounting a volume on the docker host (using VOLUME), but wouldn't that also need to be written on the writeable layer first?  Wouldn't that also give me the same error?

Comment: No.  Data exposed using `-v` is not *copied* into your container.  It is directly exposed in the container without requiring any additional space.

Answer (score 0):

So the way docker build works is this, when you use something like below

```
docker build .
```

It will send the content of the current directory to the Docker daemon. So if you are sending a context of 20GB then an additional 20GB+ of free space would be needed.

When you mount volumes on a running image, it would actually mount your folder, so no extra space would be used. But if delete the directory from inside the container, the file on the host will also be deleted.

So mounting the directory is a possible solution. Also if there are files in your current directory which you would not be interested in sending to docker daemon as a context, then you should use a `.dockerignore` to specify which files to ignore

Comment: Thanks for your response!  If I didn't want to mount a volume, ie send the data to the docker daemon, would it be possible to expand the context size? I've been searching the interwebs for awhile now and I can't figure out exactly what I need to configure.  Trying to use use the --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should set it even bigger. Use `dm.basesize=50G` and also make sure it is actually applied correctly. And set them using `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#options-per-storage-driver)

Comment: I tried to set them using the instructions on the doc but I got the following error:

$ sudo dockerd --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 4610 
WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: overlay2: Unknown option dm.basesize

This was after I stopped docker and deleted /var/lib/docker.